# Heat or Work? When equal?

Tags: thermodynamics, work

I would like to pose a fertilicious question. Namely, there is a door and some pusher. The door is supported by, say, beams or something else; and is not connected with the other device.

Question: suppose that for the time $\tau = 0.1$ (measured in seconds), the door was punched (or hit) by the force $F = 10^7$, exerted from the second device (Newtons) and get fallen apart. The distance between them is $d = 2$ meters. How we can compute the heat? What is heat at all? Does the first law of thermodynamics hold true? Masses are said to be determined by $m = 60$ kg and the pusher mechanism $M = 2.5$ tons.

My answer states that energy is one of the forms of the kinetic energy. So, KE = heat, and work does not generally correspond to the heat. We know that the differential of kinetic energy coincides with that of work. But work is change in kinetic energy. But heat? Not. That is difference. Hence, to do the task (I thought it up), we have to understand that the pusher gives the door kinetic energy by diffusion, but the hit is so quick that the door get broken due to the fact that the force does not spread over the surface but concentrate on the hit spot. We know that the door is made up of atoms. So, what the task is interactio between atoms.

If we observe that, then we are at the inertial frame and two laws of conservation holds true: momentum and enegy that are expressed by $dp = 0$ and $dE = 0$. Applying them, we can calculate something. The acceleration is given from the second Newton law. So, $Q = A$?

Comment: Personally, I conjecture that there will be an infinitesimal heat generated by punch. The work is much greater like KE.

Comment: How is this question "fertilicious"? From UrbanDictionary.com: "Describing an attractive woman that likes sex, doesn't use protection, and gets pregnant a lot."

Comment: @electronpusher, hahahaha!  That's where the pregnant pause (in answering the question) comes in.

Comment: The more complete form of the first law of thermodynamics includes not only internal energy change, but also change in kinetic energy and potential energy.  In the simpler case where the door doesn’t break, there is conversion of work to kinetic energy with no change in internal energy and no heat exchange.

Comment: That is because English is not mother tongue... I wished to say incorrect question, and its synonym is a word that resembles that one above... Please accept my apologies

Comment: @Chet Miller that is an idea on how to find the differences among these things in physics. I believed that the mechanics upon one hit transfers its kinetic energy to the door, so the head that might emit is KE. One might say that the door is at rest (not moving), so it possesses PE and uppon arrival of KE may become moving. In an attempt to justify that for the 1st law of thermodynamics, one might say that internal energy is conserved within a body. It may be PE, KE, Chemical and other types energy distributions. So, heat is one of energies?

Comment: One does remember about these formulae: $\delta A = d \left(\frac{m \cdot v^2}{2}\right) = - dU$. The first law of thermodynamics helps us define heat. But when it comes to dealing with heat, we understand that heat is transferred in various ways: radiation (Planck law), advection, convection and diffusion. In the case of the task it might be the latter, Diffusion. So, heat is like an object gives KE to another in the form heat. That is what happens inside of an electrical wire according to Joule heating in an ideal situation.

Comment: No.  Heat is energy in transit, not energy of the system.

Comment: @Chet Miller I understand that heat is not energy of any system but might be result of work. In my understanding heat can be produced by many ways: diffusion if heat has already produced ; or by chemical reactions. But the punching mechanism is not hot, and when activated acquires KE that get transferred to the door. So, it gains KE that further emitted as heat, so that the door has KE no longer. Thus, heat does not exist in its form, it is always transferred.

Comment: In the case of a chemical reaction that has taken place in a  rigid insulated container, there is no heat involved and no work involved.  The change in internal energy is zero.  If the reaction is exothermic, the decrease in internal energy resulting from making and breaking chemical bonds is exactly balanced by the increase in internal energy resulting from the rise in temperature.  If the reactor is not insulated, so that the temperature is held constant, the amount of heat that must be removed is equal to the decrease in internal energy from making and breaking chemical bonds.

Comment: @ChetMiller Re your comment about complete form of first law. You said there is no change in internal energy if the door does not break. But doesn't the impact increase motions of the molecules and atoms of the door in the area of impact?

Comment: @Bob D If it’s an elastic collision, ke is conserved.

Comment: @ChetMiller OK but I didn't see you make the assumption it is perfectly elastic, just that the door doesn't break which, I think you would agree, doesn't necessarily mean the collision is elastic.

Comment: Yes, if it is not elastic, the U will change, but to quantify it, you would need the analyze the deformation in detail, involving consideration of the door material behavior.

Comment: @ChetMiller Absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not provide solutions to homework and exercise type problems. So my answer will only address the conceptual issues you are having. In my answer I am assuming the door is your "system" and the impacting device is part of the "surroundings".

> How we can compute the heat?

There is no heat to compute in your example. See below.

> What is heat at all?

Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. In your example, there would need to be a temperature difference between the door and device that contacts it in order for heat transfer to occur.

> Does the first law of thermodynamics hold true?

Yes, but as @Chet Miller pointed out, the more complete form of the first law of thermodynamics includes not only internal energy change $\Delta U$, but also change in kinetic energy and potential energy of the center of mass with respect to an external (to the door) frame of reference. The complete form of the first law for a closed system (no change in mass) is

$$Q-W=\Delta U+\Delta KE +\Delta PE$$

Where

$Q$= heat transfer. In your case $Q=0$ since there is no stated temperature difference between the door and impact device.

$W$= Work. $W$ is negative because any work that is done is done by the device impacting the door, potentially transferring energy to the door.

$\Delta U$= Change in internal energy. That is, the changes in the kinetic energy of molecules and atoms of the door materials and changes in potential energy associated with intermolecular or interatomic forces. These changes can occur if the door breaks or otherwise collides with the device inelastically.

$\Delta KE$= a change in the kinetic energy of the door as a whole, i.e., do to translational acceleration of the center of mass of the door or angular acceleration due to rotation about the center of mass.

$\Delta PE$= a change in the potential energy of the door as a whole, e.g., a permanent change in the vertical position of the door's center of mass resulting in a change in gravitational potential energy.

> My answer states that energy is one of the forms of the kinetic
> energy. So, KE = heat, and work does not generally correspond to the
> heat

Heat does not equal kinetic energy.  If there is a temperature difference, heat can transfer kinetic energy of the atoms and molecules from one object to another changing the internal kinetic energy of the objects involved.  But heat is not the kinetic energy of the molecules and atoms themselves. Objects do not "contain" heat.

> We know that the differential of kinetic energy coincides with that of
> work. But work is change in kinetic energy.

That is correct provided *net work* is done. The work energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

> But heat? Not. That is difference.

Heat does not directly result in a change in the kinetic energy of the object as a whole. That requires net work. But heat can cause work to be done. That work, in turn, can change the kinetic energy of the overall object. An example is a gas in a piston-cylinder. Heating the gas can cause it to expand which then moves the piston. The piston thus acquires kinetic energy.

But it is the work done by the heated gas that gives the piston kinetic energy. Heat does not directly cause the piston to move. If the piston were prevented from moving (fixed in place) then heating the gas would not result in the piston moving, only an increase in the temperature and pressure of the gas.

> So, what the task is interaction between atoms.

In the case of internal energy, yes. But that would not include changes in the doors macroscopic kinetic and potential energy per the general first law equation.

> If we observe that, then we are at the inertial frame and two laws of
> conservation holds true: momentum and energy that are expressed by $dp
> > = 0$ and $dE = 0$. Applying them, we can calculate something. The acceleration is given from the second Newton law. So, $Q = A$?

The first law equation above satisfies the law of conservation of energy. I assume by $A$ you are referring to any acceleration of the door. As already noted, $Q=0$ so $Q$ can't be associated with acceleration of the door. If you apply the first law equation above, you should be able to figure out what terms could potentially cause the door to accelerate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On this forum, I never posted questions to solve my university problem. That task is from my mind when I contemplated about the Joule heating diffusion; namely, why kinetic energy was used to compute heat. The second solution in that post is more clear, because it uses the temperature term. So, I got confused and asked here another question to find out what the heat is, and why we use the 1st law of thermodynamics. I will read your answer. Feel that it would helpful. Much obliged to you and be happy. May none of orchids in your house die.

Comment: @sergeiivanov LOL. I don't have any orchids in my house because I don't have a "green thumb" . Anyway, I hope when you read my answer closely it will be of help.

Comment: Splendid! Now I see differences among these things. Your answer helped.

Comment: @sergei ivanov you are very welcome

Comment: the key is the temperature difference that was missed in my explanation. So, the inner energy is not zero but its differential is due to isolation. Next, heat is not kinetic energy, but temperature difference and heat is the energy transfer due to temperatures' difference.